# Nuget corrupt packages

Tags: msbuild, nuget, build-server, nuget-package-restore

I've setup a build server on a Rackspace cloud server (Windows 2008 R2) and my ASP.Net projects are using nuget package restore. When the build runs I get failures when nuget downloads packages, for example:

```
error : Unable to read package from path 'bootstrap.3.3.2.nupkg'
error : Unable to read package from path 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.3.0.1.nupkg'.
```

If I open the downloaded package from the C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache folder using the Nuget Package Explorer it says the file is corrupt. When I compare the file of the bootstrap package it is different than the package I have cached on my desktop computer; it looks like the last several KB are just cut off.

Deleting the cached packages and re-running the build results in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Rackspace's virtual server network cards have TCP Offload options that you can disable.

http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/disabling-tcp-offloading-in-windows-server-2012